# JHipster generated JUnit testing: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" error when running tests

Tags: jhipster, junit5

I have a JHipster application, v5.3.0. Monolith. Maven. Elasticsearch. 3 entities.

I run:

`./mvnw clean test`

5 minutes or more of test execution follows and then the following error:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

and test hangs.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded might help you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JUnit 5.3.0, this may be due to a known bug in that release.

If so, upgrading to JUnit 5.3.1 should fix it.